# uploading issue in wordpress when number of files are more than 30

Tags: arrays, wordpress, image-uploading

when we upload more than 30 images of different sizes in wordpress site, it does not upload all images in site and if we print request data ($_REQUEST and $_FILES) it prints empty array.
and how can we print that error message in wordpress?

please help

Answer (score 0):

Change `max_file_uploads` in your php.ini or add a `ini_set('max_file_uploads', $someNumber);` in your code.

Comment: Seems that changing this value is a protection against attacks.

Can you try adding this in your .htaccess:

    php_value max_file_uploads 200

Comment: if i try in .htaccess,it gives 500 Internal Server Error